# failed to install pkg-config

Tags: ros, player

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i'm new to ros and have been trying to install the player ros package from http://www.ros.org/wiki/player. When I run rosmake player it complains that pkg-config isn't installed. I then tried to run rosdep install player but it fails to install pkg-config.

```
calum0@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/player$ rosdep install player
Failed to find rosdep pkg-config for package player on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install pkg-config
calum0@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/player$ rosmake player
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['player']                                  
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/calum0/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120411-180619
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['player'] to:
['player']                             
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages player.  This may take a few seconds.
Failed to find rosdep pkg-config for package player on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
WARNING: Rosdeps [u'pkg-config'] could not be resolved
Failed to find rosdep pkg-config for package player on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
[ rosmake ] rosdep check failed to find system dependencies: pkg-config         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> player [ make ]                                        
[ rosmake ] All 9 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make wipe
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/calum0/ros_workspace/player'
  rm -rf build/player-svn/build
  rm -rf player installed wiped
  rm -rf build
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/calum0/ros_workspace/player'
  touch wiped
  touch: cannot touch `wiped': Permission denied
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package player written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/calum0/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120411-180619/player/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< player [FAIL] [ 0.01 seconds ]                         
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package player. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 1 failures.                                   
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/calum0/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120411-180619            
[ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: pkg-config Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install player`
calum0@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/player$ 

calum0@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/player$ rosdep install player
Failed to find rosdep pkg-config for package player on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install pkg-config
calum0@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/player$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31615/failed-to-install-pkg-config/) by [Roy89](https://answers.ros.org/users/2154/roy89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing the stack erratic_robot which contains rosdep.yaml which defines how to install pkg-config.

You need to checkout all of erratic_robot or copy the rosdep.yaml file into the player directory and make sure it's not within a stack, as it appears to be in your file layout.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1